# Python poetry says my conda env "seems to be broken"

Tags: python, conda, python-poetry

I'm attempting to use `poetry` with a `conda` environment, but `poetry` doesn't seem to like my conda environment. When I run `poetry install`, I get

```
The virtual environment found in C:/Users/rdprice/Apps/Anaconda3/envs/kalman 
seems to be broken. Recreating virtualenv kalman-HAVrs3Fl-py3.10 in 
C:/Users/rdprice/AppData/Local/pypoetry/Cache/virtualenvs/kalman-HAVrs3Fl-py3.10
Using virtualenv: C:/Users/rdprice/AppData/Local/pypoetry/Cache/virtualenvs/kalman-HAVrs3Fl-py3.10
```

The error "seems to be broken" gives me very little to go on.

If I run the python interpreter inside the virtualenv, I can import my `kalman` package just fine, but that misses the point of having the `conda` environment. I would like to use the python interpreter and packages in the `conda` environment for development.

Is this possible?

This is on Windows 10 running MSYS2. Here is my `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "kalman"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Kalman filters for ...."
authors = ["Rodney Price"]
license = "None"
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

and the `poetry.lock` file:

```
package = []

[metadata]
lock-version = "1.1"
python-versions = "^3.9"
content-hash = "ce2aa767160f871dd3652615ba0a0dceb7733d62eb8cb4665b87f30a562e3adf"

[metadata.files]
```

and the `conda` environment, obtained from running `conda env export --from-history | grep -v "^prefix"`:

```
name: kalman
channels:     
  - defaults  
dependencies: 
  - python=3.9
```

**Edit:**

After installing `poetry` into the `conda` environment, `poetry install` no longer gives me the "seems to be broken" error, and I can use the `conda` environment. Here's what `poetry install` returns now:

```
C:\Users\rdprice\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\kalman\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
Using virtualenv: C:\Users\rdprice\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\kalman
```

It would be nice to turn off the warning, but it seems to work.

Comment: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2756